# Invalid Factor Level, NA generated R

Tags: string, r, replace, numeric

Sample of the data I am working with below. I already omitted all rows with a "NA" in them.

```
gss.s[1:5,]
      abany          advfront   arrest
2      YES             Agree       NO
3      YES    Strongly agree       YES
10     YES             Agree       YES
16     YES             Agree       NO
21      NO    Strongly agree       NO
```

I am trying to replace the "YES" with a 1 in the abany column and "NO" with -1 in abany column. I tried using replace replace(gss.s[,1], "YES", 1) but got the error Invalid Factor Level, NA generated. I read a previous post about this same problem and couldn't figure out how to apply the solution to my problem.

Comment: the issue is that 1 and -1 are not defined as levels for your factor, which probably only includes YES and NO. you can add them as levels, or redefine the variable type to character rather than factor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `ifelse()` on the column, changing all values at once.

```
gss.s$abany <- ifelse(gss.s$abany == "YES", 1, -1)
gss.s
##    abany       advfront arrest
## 2      1          Agree     NO
## 3      1 Strongly agree    YES
## 10     1          Agree    YES
## 16     1          Agree     NO
## 21    -1 Strongly agree     NO
```

Comment: One other quick question. How would I replace strongly agree with 2 in the advfront column, agree with 1, disagree with -1, and strongly disagree with -2. I tried doing it one at a time with ifelse(), but it didn't work. Here is what I did     gss.s$advfront <- ifelse(gss.s$advfront == "Disagree", -1, gss.s$advfront). This didn't leave the values that were not "Disagree" as the original values. Do you know a way to do this. BTW sorry for the horrible formatting. I couldn't get a code block in the comment for some reason.

Comment: Sorry for not responding to this comment.  I must have forgotten.  I assume you've got it sorted out now, seeing as it's a year and a half ago?

Answer (score 2):

```
y <- data.frame ("abany"=c("YES","YES","YES","YES","NO"), 
            "advfront"=c("Agree","Strongly Agree","Agree","Agree","Strongly Agree"),
            "arrest"=c("NO","YES","YES","NO","NO"))
```

I would try another way:
Convert factor column to character

```
y$abany <- as.character.factor (y$abany)
```

So now you don't have any problem to change values of the column

```
y[y$abany=="YES", "abany"] <- 1
y[y$abany=="NO", "abany"] <- -1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a vector in which you define the changes you would like to make. It is a lot quicker if you have big datasets compared to `ifelse` statements.

```
translate <- c(YES=1,NO=-1)
gss.s$abany2 <- translate[as.character(gss.s$abany)] 
gss.s

#   abany       advfront arrest abany2
# 1   YES          Agree     NO      1
# 2   YES Strongly agree    YES      1
# 3   YES          Agree    YES      1
# 4   YES          Agree     NO      1
# 5    NO Strongly agree     NO     -1
```

You also don't have to struggle with nested `ifelse` functions if you have multiple changes to make:

```
translate2 <- c('Strongly agree'=2,Agree=1,Disagree=-1,'Strongly disagree'=-2 )
gss.s$advfront2 <- translate2[as.character(gss.s$advfront)]
gss.s

#   abany       advfront arrest abany2 advfront2
# 1   YES          Agree     NO      1         1
# 2   YES Strongly agree    YES      1         2
# 3   YES          Agree    YES      1         1
# 4   YES          Agree     NO      1         1
# 5    NO Strongly agree     NO     -1         2
```